# Return all divisors of a number - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to find all divisors of a number in Python. I'm doing this greatly in Javascript, C#, Java, but my Python code work only with `print` statement correctly. But I don't want to print divisors, I want to assign them to some variable, or displaying them calling function in `print`.

```
def mainFunction(number):
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return i
```

Comment: You can append them into a list and afterwards return the list

Comment: @EnriqueBet, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example saving them in a list

```
def return_divisors(number):
      return [x for x in range(1,number+1) if number % x == 0 ]

print(return_divisors(1))
print(return_divisors(2))
print(return_divisors(10))
print(return_divisors(121))

[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 5, 10]
[1, 11, 121]
```

Comment: Result appended to a list automatically because of brackets after ```return``` ?

Comment: Exactly! also `return list( x for x in range(1,number+1) if number % x == 0)`  would have done the same thing.  You can store the list to var like this `name_var = return_divisors(11)`

Comment: Got that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, your function will return on the first possible divisor (so almost always 1). If you want to keep searching after your first finding, you must save it, e.g. in a list (or use a generator etc).

```
def mainFunction(number):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors
```

Answer (score 2):

One more, using generator:

```
def mainFunction(number):
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            yield i

for divisor in mainFunction(10):
        print( divisor )
```